# Open a .pdf file

Tags: vba, excel, pdf, iframe

I am trying to open a .pdf file within Excel like an iframe in HTML. 
My requirement is:

1. Save the path of multiple PDF files in Excel.
2. Excel should open each .pdf file within Excel itself (no need to open that in a separate .pdf window).
3. It should be like iframe in HTML. The user should be able
   to view the .pdf within Excel itself.

I know this is little weird, but can anybody help me?

Comment: Given that you probably do not want to have to install a redistributable on every computer that will be opening your workbook, I would suggest embedding a browser into a userform. Most everyone already has a browser add-on that can open a PDF and it should be close enough to your iframe idea.

Comment: Hi Jeeped; I never thought to that idea. Let me work-around and I shall post the outcome. Thanks :D

Answer (score 0):

you could probably get the filenames via vba.
here's some that claim to work:

[Loop through files in a folder using VBA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10380312/loop-through-files-in-a-folder-using-vba)

So far as opening a pdf in excel - thats kinda pushing it.
Since your request is exotic I can think of an exotic workaround:

If you can spare the interactivity you can simply make copies and convert your pdfs to word formats to work with them and load them in that way. I've seen people convert pdfs to Jpgs just to load them in some other documents but thats rudimentary and really fringe.

Otherwise you are facing a lot of custom coding that needs to make it possible.

Comment: Hi Helena4, thanks for the reply. Here, I do not wanna convert PDF to word/JPEG because te users need to use the pdf tools to check certain items in the pdf and update that to excel. :(. Any spark? thanks in advance.

Comment: What awesome tools does pdf have that word 2013 can't compete with? Either way - if you find a coder to make it happen for you. Either post it for free or sell it online, i imagine its not just you that would like to load pdfs in excel.